# Cypher - Maximum Connected Common Subgraph

Tags: cypher

I have a set of match clauses as follows:

```
MATCH (target:C2)-[rvard:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarf:LOCATION), 
(nvara:LOCATION)-[rvara:CONNECTED]->(nvarb:LOCATION), 
(nvarc:C1)-[rvarb:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarb:LOCATION), 
(nvard:LOCATION)-[rvarc:CONNECTED]->(nvare:LOCATION), 
(nvarg:LOCATION)-[rvare:CONNECTED]->(nvarh:LOCATION), 
(target:C2)-[rvarf:HAS_VALUE]->(nvari:TRUE), 
(nvarj:LOCATION)-[rvarg:CONNECTED]->(nvark:LOCATION), 
(nvarl:AGENT)-[rvarh:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarf:LOCATION), 
(nvarm:LOCATION)-[rvari:CONNECTED]->(nvarn:LOCATION), 
(nvarm:LOCATION)-[rvarj:CONNECTED]->(nvark:LOCATION), 
(nvarm:LOCATION)-[rvark:CONNECTED]->(nvaro:LOCATION), 
(nvarp:AGENT)-[rvarl:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarq:LOCATION), 
(nvarq:LOCATION)-[rvarm:CONNECTED]->(nvaro:LOCATION), 
(nvarb:LOCATION)-[rvarn:CONNECTED]->(nvarm:LOCATION), 
(nvarf:LOCATION)-[rvaro:CONNECTED]->(nvarh:LOCATION), 
(nvarf:LOCATION)-[rvarp:CONNECTED]->(nvare:LOCATION), 
(nvare:LOCATION)-[rvarq:CONNECTED]->(nvarq:LOCATION)  
RETURN DISTINCT target
```

All clauses together create a connected subgraph.

I want to adapt this query so that Cypher finds the target that is constrained by the most amount of match clauses, i.e., removing the least amount of clauses that do not match. One way to do this is to make all clauses optional, collect non-null relations and select the target that has the largest set of collected relations.

Any efficient search for matches would begin at possible values for the target variable and expand from these along relations connected to the target via a path. However, I do not believe that Cypher has this optimisation approach, and as a consequence, this approach is completely intractable, even for modest sized graphs of 100 nodes.

Is there a tractable solution to this problem in Cypher? If not, how would I approach this with the traversal framework?

I just learnt of the cost planner in Neo4j 2.2. It may be the case that the cost planner might automatically generate a good query plan for this sort of query though it currently does not work for this sort of query. If this is the case it would be good to know if this might be possible in this version of Neo4j or in near extensions to it.